# Pass variable parameters as arguments to POST method of node request module for firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase cloud functions. Wrote a function using node request module POST method which passes some values as arguments to the server. The code works fine with static values in arguments but not receiving response for dynamic values in arguments. The function gets executed but not returning any response from server.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var request = require('request');

exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
const email = user.email;
const uid = user.uid;
return sendWelcomeEmail(email,uid);
});

function sendWelcomeEmail(email,uid){

var dataString =  'excessToken'=uid&'name'==='assadas'&'emailId'=email ;           

var options = {
    url: 'http://ip:port/someapi',
    method: 'POST',
    body : dataString

};



  function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log(body);
    }
  }

  request(options, callback);

}
```

excessToken=uid and emailId=email are the variable arguments which have to be posted on to the server.

Comment: Whats going with your `dataString ` variable? You need to concatenate properly using `+` or `concat()`.

Comment: @ScottSword can u please elaborate the syntax??

Comment: Just see what Doug just posted.

Answer (score 1):

Your dataString looks like it wasn't composed very well.  You're mixing up a variety of JavaScript operations and substrings.  It'll be easier to write if you use backtick string composition that lets you interpolate variables:

```
var dataString = `excessToken=${uid}&name=assadas&emailId=${email}`;
```

It will also help your debugging if you use console.log() to log values that you'd like to know what they are at runtime.  This will help you diagnose problems faster.

Long term, you should also look into escaping the values that you insert into a string like this.  You can't just have any old characters in a post body that's formatted like a query string.